# Reusing Types between ADO.NET Data Services and WCF service in Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight, wcf-data-services

I have an ADO.NET Data Service and a regular WCF service. I'm using both these services in a Silverlight application.  The WCF sercvice has an operation which has a parameter of the same type as an entity returned by the ADO.NET Data Service. The problem is that silverlight generates different types for the WCF service and for the ADO.NET service so passing the result from one to the other would require extra code. I would like to reuse the types generated for the ADO.NET Data Service proxy for the WCF serice proxy as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this [tip](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2010/01/27/tip-52-how-to-re-use-types-with-the-data-services-client.aspx) from Alex James.